# Change data hover line color in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to change this particular hover line in an area chart. Which option should I change? I checked the documentation but changing the value for `lineColor` and `lineWidth` only changes the color of the outline of each data point. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: What kind of chart is this one?  The theme editor details some options that can be changed. http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series/sand-signika  - Also you may be able to inspect element and that may give you some clue on what to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change **`tooltip.crosshairs`** options to change the **width**, **color**, **dashStyle** and **zIndex** of the line. Here's the code for width and color:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: [{
            width: 3,
            color: 'green'
    }]
}
```

The first object of the array is for the **xAxis**, the second for the **yAxis**. Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ywoqty7t/).

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't change the color of the vertical line itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use css.

```
  crosshairs: false
```